# Telerik Blazor responsive grid

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, telerik-grid

i'm using telerik blazor grid. i tried adaptive grid layout example Reference link [Telerik Adaptive Grid](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/cHblbdPP47yR258n27?_ga=2.226882717.1254464772.1704132248-1139209025.1701887927&_gl=1*1vy5mv6*_ga*MTEzOTIwOTAyNS4xNzAxODg3OTI3*_ga_9JSNBCSF54*MTcwNDEzMjI1Mi40LjEuMTcwNDEzMzIyMy42MC4wLjA.*_gcl_au*Mzk2MTg2MDY5LjE3MDE4ODc5Mjc.)  but it does provide responsiveness on listing of elements. For example if there is static grid like one row with two columns, one column have any image and second column any text or form. is there any way to make responsive grid for all devices. [image]

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know telerik doesn't provide built it responsive for Grid but there's a work around you can use

[Responsive / adaptive Grid for mobile devices][1]
[1]: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/